# STS is very slow rebuilding workspace

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Even with the Spring builders and validators disabled in the project, STS is very slow at rebuilding a workspace. I typically see this when I have updated the repo from git, then hit "refresh" on the project. What happens is that there are several threads running BeansConfig.executePostProcessor, with one active one (sample stack trace below) and several others BLOCKED on UrlResourceFinder.findResource. Is there a way to avoid waiting for minutes at a time for STS?

```html
"Background Thread-41 (Spring IDE/3.6.3)" daemon prio=6 tid=0x54499800 nid=0x45e4 runnable [0x5e79e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getLastModifiedTime(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.lastModified(File.java:937)
        at org.apache.xbean.classloader.NonLockingJarFile.clearJarEntryCacheIfFileHasChanged(NonLockingJarFile.java:147)
        at org.apache.xbean.classloader.NonLockingJarFile.getJarEntryCache(NonLockingJarFile.java:157)
        at org.apache.xbean.classloader.NonLockingJarFile.getJarEntry(NonLockingJarFile.java:213)
        at org.apache.xbean.classloader.JarResourceLocation.getResourceHandle(JarResourceLocation.java:42)
        at org.apache.xbean.classloader.UrlResourceFinder.findResource(UrlResourceFinder.java:115)
        - locked <0x2b0000d0> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.apache.xbean.classloader.JarFileClassLoader$3.run(JarFileClassLoader.java:220)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.xbean.classloader.JarFileClassLoader.findResource(JarFileClassLoader.java:218)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.java.ProjectClassLoaderCache$FilteringNonLockingJarFileClassLoader.findResource(ProjectClassLoaderCache.java:517)
        at org.apache.xbean.classloader.MultiParentClassLoader.getResource(MultiParentClassLoader.java:266)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.java.ProjectClassLoaderCache$FilteringNonLockingJarFileClassLoader.getResource(ProjectClassLoaderCache.java:529)
        at org.apache.xbean.classloader.MultiParentClassLoader.getResource(MultiParentClassLoader.java:252)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.java.ProjectClassLoaderCache$FilteringNonLockingJarFileClassLoader.getResource(ProjectClassLoaderCache.java:529)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(URLClassLoader.java:227)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.java.ProjectClassLoaderCache$FilteringNonLockingJarFileClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ProjectClassLoaderCache.java:535)
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:155)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.type.asm.SimpleClassReaderFactory.getClassReader(SimpleClassReaderFactory.java:67)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.type.asm.CachingClassReaderFactory.getClassReader(CachingClassReaderFactory.java:61)
        - locked <0x34c412f8> (a java.util.HashMap)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.type.asm.SimpleClassReaderFactory.getClassReader(SimpleClassReaderFactory.java:63)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.java.classreading.JdtConnectedMetadataReader.<init>(JdtConnectedMetadataReader.java:42)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.java.classreading.JdtMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(JdtMetadataReaderFactory.java:53)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.java.classreading.CachingJdtMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingJdtMetadataReaderFactory.java:38)
        - locked <0x34c41340> (a java.util.HashMap)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:73)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:274)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.metadata.process.JdtConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcess(JdtConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:87)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$4.run(BeansConfig.java:765)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig.executePostProcessor(BeansConfig.java:751)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig.postProcess(BeansConfig.java:634)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig.access$8(BeansConfig.java:593)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:453)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What you describe sounds like a 'flurry' of resource update events caused by the git update is not being handled efficiently. I am not sure there is much that you can do to avoid it. It may be worth raising a bug report on the STS issue tracker. If at all possible try to attach a sample project and/or detailed instructions to reproduce the behavior that spawns these threads. The issue tracker is here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS

Comment: Please file a bug in the STS issue tracker for this (as Kris mentioned). And if you are not able to attach a sample project that illustrates the problem it could be useful to record a profiling session (for example using YourKit) while this problems appear and attach that to the issue. That would be awesome.

Comment: Thank you. I have gone ahead and opened STS-4084, opened under the general performance improvements issue. I attached a profiling session from the JDK's JMC tool. https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4084